# Windows7-Dual Boot Ubuntu fails

Tags: dual-boot

I wanted to set up my new MSI laptop to dual boot windows 7 Pro and Ubuntu 14.04.2-desktop-amd64. Laptop has a 1TB hard disk, Intel 4810MQ CPU (2.8 GHZ) 8 GB of ram. I used the disk manager to make a  100GB nest for ubuntu.
When I run the .iso disk, UBUNTU with 5 white dots appear on the screen with the dots turning red over and over again for hours and that's all that happens.
I put the .iso disk into my XP Pro desk top and I get the UBUNTU install screen.  One the MSI laptop I do get the dual boot dos window and then UBUNTU and the dots.
What did I do wrong?
I can't run UBUNTU from CD/DVD either.

Comment: What is your .iso disk medium? Are you using a CD/DVD/USB? Different hardware between the desktop and the laptop. If it's not working with a CD/DVD, can you try with a USB Thumb Drive? Point being: You'll definitely want to try with different installation methods if the first did not work.

Comment: So I would restate your problem as not so much "dual boot fails" but "cannot boot from install disk".

Comment: Did system originally come with Windows 8 and you installed Windows 7? Or real question is, was system gpt and now it is MBR(msdos). Windows does not convert correctly and leaves backup gpt partition table.  If Windows 7 is UEFI, then be sure to boot Ubuntu installer in UEFI boot mode. What video, Intel or add in chip?

Comment: I said windows 7 Pro an MSI  laptop. I don't know what gpt is. Never had this problem before. UEFI, don't have a clue.